# Justification for "reducing integrals" in the virial expansion for gases

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integration, phase-space

I have been following this document (https://sites.chem.utoronto.ca/chemistry/jmschofi/chm427/gases.pdf) regarding the virial expansion of gases and on finding the virial coefficients.

On Page 7, they do the following:
$$Z_3 = \int _V d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2 d\mathbf{r}_3 f_{12}f_{23}$$
where $f_{ij} = f(|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j|)$, the Meyer-f function. We are integrating over the entire phase space, with $\mathbf{r}$ being the 3D position vector.
They say that the above integral is reducible, and reduce it as,
$$Z_3 = \int _V d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2 d\mathbf{r}_3 f_{12}f_{23} = \int _V d\mathbf{r}_{12} d\mathbf{r}_{2} d\mathbf{r}_{23} f_{12}f_{23}\\=V\left(\int _V d\mathbf{r}_{12}f_{12}\right)\left( \int _Vd\mathbf{r}_{23}f_{23}\right)$$

My question is, why is this last step valid?

I understand substitution (like $u$-substitution, or trig substitution when we are learning basic integrals) of variables within an integral sign, but this seems to be a bit more than that, right?
I made the substitution, $$\mathbf{r}_1 \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_{12}\\ \mathbf{r}_{3} \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_{23}$$
But, if $r_{12} = r_1 - r_2$, then shouldn't $d\mathbf{r}_{12} = d\mathbf{r}_1 - d\mathbf{r}_2$? Furthermore, if $f_{12}$ and $f_{23}$ have a dependence on $\mathbf{r}_2$, why are we ignoring that dependence and just integrating it out?

I am really struggling to understand why that step is allowed.

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a single variable integral and you should recall what you learn in multiple variable calculus --- the change of variable should follow by Jacobian. Obviously here the Jacobian is 1. Then after change of variable $f_{12}(r)=f_{12}(r_1-r_2)=f_{12}(r_{12})$ would depend on $r_{12}$ only and has nothing to do with $r_2$ and you could integrate $r_2$ out.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _V d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2 d\mathbf{r}_3 f_{12}f_{23} =\int_V d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2 f_{12} \int_V d\mathbf{r}_3 f_{23} = -\int_V d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2 f_{12} \int_V d\mathbf{r}_{23} f_{23} = \int_V d\mathbf{r}_{12} d\mathbf{r}_{2} d\mathbf{r}_{23} f_{12}f_{23} =\int_V d\mathbf{r}_2 \Big(\int_V d\mathbf{r}_{12}f_{12}\Big)\Big(\int_V d\mathbf{r}_{23}f_{23}\Big) = V\Big(\int_V d\mathbf{r}_{12}f_{12}\Big)\Big(\int_V d\mathbf{r}_{23}f_{23}\Big).$$

The first equality is just to separate the integrals for clarity. The second equality comes from defining $\mathbf{r}_{23} = \mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_3$ and the integral over $\mathbf{r}_3$ is performed with fixed $\mathbf{r}_2$ means that $d\mathbf{r}_{23} = -d\mathbf{r}_3$. The tricky part is that you have to consider how the boundary of the volume $V$ changes, however we assume thermodynamical limit (or at least a macroscopic volume so that the integration bounds stay the same). In the third equality we pull the same trick with the other coordinates $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$. In the fourth equality we use that now $\mathbf{r}_{12}$, $\mathbf{r}_2,\mathbf{r}_{23}$ are independent integration variables and that $f_{12}$ depends on $\mathbf{r}_{12}$ only and $f_{23}$ on $\mathbf{r}_{23}$ only. The last equality is simple.